# Java match Code for Number "0" and "1"

Tags: java, regex

My Problem.

A string can only contain the numbers "0" and / or "1".

1. it is possible to check the string with "match" to 1 and 0?
2. if yes, how do I have to "match" write.

   ```
    if (eingabe.length() <= 0 || eingabe.matches("[0-1]")) {

                   System.err.println("Bitte geben Sie mindestens eine Ziffer von 0 bis 1 ein.");
                   System.exit(1);
               }
   ```

Thank you.

Comment: `[0-1]` means `1 character, of value 0 or 1`

Comment: can you just do `eingabe.equals("0") || eingabe.equals("1")`?

Comment: You're close, but (1) your `matches` only works if the string is exactly one character, and (2) you're printing your error message if the string **does** match, instead of when it doesn't.  To fix (2), use `!eingabe.matches`.  To fix (1), use `+` in your regular expression (I'll let you look it up [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) so you can learn more).

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones The error message says "Please enter at least one digit", and your code only checks for inputs of exactly one digit.

Comment: What are the valid values of `eingabe`? *Provide examples* in the question.

Comment: The values ​​for "eingabe" are: 011001 or 11001 or 00110

Comment: @carlie What about "asdfs0adsdf", or "0asdfasdf"?  If these are invalid, you'll need to check for any non-0 or non-1 characters, instead of only for 0 or 1.  If they're valid, then the other suggested regexes ([01]+) should catch them.

Comment: So the right thing to do is clearly `if (! eingabe.matches("[01]+")) { ...` - can someone post this as an answer so we can all go home?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (eingabe.matches("[01]*")) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I don't think she wants to allow `,` characters in the input.

Comment: how is your regex different from the OP's?  I'm not saying that it isn't, but you might want to draw more attention to the difference

Comment: Well, OP's regex only accepts a String of 1 character. However, this Regex accepts a variable length String. I would, though, make it `[01]+` instead of `[01]*` as he doesn't want an empty String

Answer (score 0):

u can use this method to check the each char in the string : str.charAt(INDEX);

just do a loop on your string , and check each index if ==0 or ==1

Answer (score 0):

if its a simple check then you can avoid regex although not recommended

if using regex follow as suggested by ajb (third edit to your question )

if avoiding regex you can use below

```
private  boolean containsZeroOrOne(String c){

if(c.indexOf('0') >= 0 || c.indexOf('1') >= 0)
return true;

return false;
```

}

Comment: It appears that the OP is looking for strings that consist entirely of 0's and 1's, not strings that simply contain a 0 or a 1.